# How can I kill gnome shell widgets?

Tags: command-line, gnome, kill

I have some gnome shell widgets that I need to be closed. I am unable to find which processes are behind them.

Any idea how can I kill them?

Comment: @don_crissti This kind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110163/creating-gnome-shell-applets-widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try using `ps` to determine what processes are running out of everything, e.g.:

```
ps -ely | grep -i $PROCESSNAME
```

Guessing at what the widget names will be:

```
ps -ely | grep -i gnome
```

Is very likely to list them all.

Answer (score 1):

I just `scp`ed the old good xkill on that machine and it worked like a charm.